# What does slash in a header file name mean?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I was reading the gcc [gnu-online-docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax). I am confused about what it mentions regarding a `\` or `/`in a header file name.

It says:

> However, if backslashes occur within file, they are considered
>   ordinary text characters, not escape characters. None of the character
>   escape sequences appropriate to string constants in C are processed.
>   Thus, `#include "x\n\\y"` specifies a filename containing three
>   backslashes. (Some systems interpret ‘\’ as a pathname separator. All
>   of these also interpret ‘`/`’ the same way. It is most portable to use
>   only ‘`/`’.)

What does it mean by "some systems" in this paragraph? Does it mean the implementation depends upon the OS - Windows/Linux? (I know in `#include <linux/module.h>`, `/` specifies a path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, both <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd> function as *pathname component separators* (dividing the name of a directory from the name of something within the directory).  On basically all other operating systems in common use today, only <kbd>/</kbd> serves this function.<sup>1</sup>

By taking <kbd>\</kbd> literally in header-file names, instead of an escape character as it is in normal strings, GCC's preprocessor accommodates Windows-specific code written with backslashes, e.g.

```
#include <sys\types.h>
```

where it is exceedingly unlikely that the programmer intended to include a file whose name is '`sys ypes.h`' (that blank before the 'y' is a hard tab).   The text in the manual is intended to inform you that such code will not work if moved to a Unixy system, but that if you write it with a forward slash instead, it *will* work on Windows.

I happen to have written the paragraph you quote, but that was more than ten years ago now, and I don't remember why I didn't use the word "Windows".

<sup>1</sup> VMS and some IBM mainframe OSes have entirely different pathname syntax, but these have never been well-supported by GCC, and it is my understanding that surviving installations tend to have a POSIX compatibility layer installed anyway.

Comment: Ok.. but isn't GCC is responsible for this interpretation and conversion? And GCC is supported both on linux and windows (MinGW), so why the difference ?

Comment: GCC passes the string `foo\bar.h` verbatim to `open`.  It is the operating system that parses it for pathname separators.  It does "interpret" the string insofar as it does *not* treat \-whatever as an escape sequence (contra regular string constants), I suppose; but *that* behavior *is* consistent across all supported host operating systems.

Comment: Ohkkk.. got it.. Thanks! And woah.. you wrote that documentation? It is my honor directly talking to you about it :)

Comment: ... If I had it to do over again I might well have GCC rewrite `foo\bar.h` as `foo/bar.h` before passing it to `open`, but if you give me a time machine I'm going to use it to make Gary Kildall use `-` instead of `/` to introduce options in CP/M, so we won't *have* this mess in the first place.

Comment: I hope they realize the same thing and change it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in ordinary strings, `\n` is a newline, `\t` is a tab, `\a` is an alert, etc.

The text means that if you write:

```
#include <sys\alert.h>
```

the `\a` sequence is treated as two characters, backslash and 'a', and not as a single character 'alert'.  That is, the file is called `alert.h` and is found in a directory `sys` somewhere in one of the directories that the compiler searches for headers.  Normally, inside a string, `"sys\alert.h"` would mean a name 's', 'y', 's', <kbd>backspace</kbd>, 'l', 'e', 'r', 't', '.', 'h'.

Similarly for:

```
#include <sys\backtrack.h>
#include <sys\file.h>
#include <sys\newton.h>
#include <sys\register.h>
#include <sys\time.h>
#include <sys\vtable.h>
```

(where I made up names as seemed to be convenient, and the `sys` can be replaced by any other directory name, and the `<>` by `""`).

```
#include <sys\386.h>
#include <sys\xdead.h>
#include <sys\ucafe.h>
#include <sys\U00DEFACED.h>
```

are also treated as regular strings rather than containing octal, hexadecimal, or Unicode escapes.

Windows is the main system where `\` is used as the formal path element separator.  However, even on Windows, the API treats `/` as if it were `\`.

Comment: You mean the slash `\` is not escaped and is part of the file name ? In your example, then it should mean `sys\backtrack` is a *Name* and it doesn't mean including a file named `backtrack` in folder `sys` ? This is kind of confusing, please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: No; it means that `sys\backtrack.h` _is_ a file in the `sys` folder, not that the header name is 's', 'y', 's', backspace, 'a', 'c', ...